# error de compilación en visual studio 2019

Tags: c++

soy nuevo programando y tengo un problema con mi visual studio 2019 , siempre que intento compilar algo en un proyecto vacío CLR.Net Framework el visual me dice que hay un error en compilación y luego procede a decir que no se puede iniciar el problema debido a que el sistema no encuentra el archivo especificado , ya llevo bastantes días con el problema y no le encuentro solución. muy agradecido de su ayuda

he tratado de descargar los componentes necesarios, aparte de desinstalar y reinstalar visual  , pero aun así no encuentro la solución. Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme

Comment: CLR.Net está relacionado con la plataforma .NET, no con C++ nativo

Comment: Si ver el error y sin ver el código no podemos ayudarte.